# Are the decrement and increment shorthand operators are types of shorthand assignment operators?

Tags: java

There are many shorthand assignment operators (arithmetic and bitwise) such as `*=`, `+=`, `%=`, `\=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `^=`, `&=`, `|=`.

But the pre- and postfix decrement and increment shorthand unary operators also involve assignment, are they also types of shorthand assignment operators?

Comment: `x += 1` is shorthand for `x = x + 1`. Why do you think that the inclusion of assignment makes it not shorthand?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html lists `expr+` as a 'postfix' operator, `+=` as an 'assignment' operator. 'shorthand' is no term used there. So what is your question?

Comment: @Michael Because most documentations categorize only those operators as shorthand assignment operators that include the assignment operator. But I believe x++ and ++x are also shorthand assignment olerators, are not they?

Comment: @LutzHorn okay, then my question is, can you consider the decrement and increment operators also assignment operaotrs?

Comment: Pretty sure shorthand is just a regular English word used to indicate writing something in a shorter way, that means the same thing.  Are you asking what is _officially_ the name of them?  Talking day to day I doubt anyone would care if you call them shorthand assignment operators.

Comment: `x §= y` is a "short-hand" for `x = x § y;`. The de- and increment operators are a kind of short-hand too, but the postfix versions do more, returning the original value.

Comment: @Nexevis I want to know whether the decrement and increment operators are officially categorized as types of assignment operators or not

Comment: Well @Lutz Horn just linked you the official documentation, and you did not like that one.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer Yes. The `+=`, `-=` and so on are "assignment operators".

Comment: @Nexevis I had another look at that documentation and does not list ++ and — in the list of assignment operators. I like that

Comment: @LutzHorn sorry, the doc you linked actually answers the question because increment and decrement are not listed as assignment operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not according to the language specification.

`++` and `--` are listed here under 'unary operators'

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15

and not here under 'assignment operators'

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26

Answer (score 1):

What you describe as shorthand operators are *Compound Assignment Operators*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

The *Pre-* and *Postfix Operators* are called just that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2

None of them are called shorthand.